# How do I set a parent in a Universal Windows App with VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, uwp, uwp-xaml

I'm trying to create a new "tile" in a stackpanel. This tile needs to have a checkbox on the left, a title at the top, and text content just below the title.

```
Private Sub buttonAdd_Tapped(sender As Object, e As TappedRoutedEventArgs) Handles buttonAdd.Tapped
    Dim NewTask as New TaskControl 'TaskControl is a UserControl

    taskTile.Parent = TaskStackPanel
End Sub
```

However, it says the Parent property is read-only (so is the Children property). Can anybody help me with this, or is there an easier way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to it the other way around, add the Grid to the panel's `Children` collection.

Btw creating controls in code is usually not a good idea.

Comment: "creating controls in code is usually not a good idea" - how else can controls be added at run-time?

Comment: You can use an ItemsControl bound to a collection and add items to this collection. Or at least create a UserControl with everything you need (Grid + 2x TextBlock) and add this UserControl ..

Comment: I suppose I could use a UserControl, but I'm sure if those work in Universal Windows Apps.

Comment: It is a collection, add an item to it

Comment: It needs to be `YourCollection.Children.Add("Your New Grid")`;

Comment: Oh, got it. Thanks Igor and AVK!